# Problems with transaction in my Gnosis APP

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are sending a transaction through the https://app.safe.global/ but when running the simulation it gives error validating the approve.   What happens is that, the simulation reports that it's checking the allowance against the contract implementation and not against the USDT proxy.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do just the approve. I think it'll work fine. And the failure is coming from the deposit transaction. This could be for various reasons, most probable are: a) the depositor (safe?) actually doesn't have enough USDT, b) when you set up approve you missed a few zeroes (make sure to add 6 zeroes to the amount)

Comment: It has already been tried that way, doing the approve first and then the deposit and it gives the same error. The wallet does have enough USDT funds, the problem is that it validates the allowance in the implementation 0x7FFB3d63701448888b63fb9858E279385685AFc1e2 and not in the proxy 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F